# socket.io - engine error handshaking to transport websocket

Tags: node.js, azure, apache, websocket, socket.io

I really don't know why I am getting this error.

`socket.io - engine error handshaking to transport websocket`

It's working on local server but not working on live server. I have checked this whole functionality on my local server and It's working.

On live server (configured by client developer) maybe misconfigure `reverse_proxy` and other server related things. Apache installed on live server(`azure`).

I have already check port and everything but don't know why `socket` not communicate with server.

When I tried with `ip` and `domain` `socket` gives us `timeout` error.

I have no idea about server configuration.

Please assist me where I made mistakes.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am connecting `socket.io` on both side.

Comment: Then, you probably have a proxy configuration error that isn't permitting the incoming webSocket request through to your server.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have checked proxy but no luck.

Comment: Can you show us the web server config?